# mvc Partial views and model issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

> model 1 dbclient
>
> clientID,client(name),clientcontact , and an ICollection Countys
>
> model 2 dbcounty
>
> countyID,clientID,county(name),countyOther

**Overview:**

Creating a Client View that has a (View) Countys actionlink - done + working

Creating a County View that has a (create,edit,delete,details) actionlink - done + partially working

to get to my Countys:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Countys", "Index", "County", new { id=item.ClientID },null)
```

from countys to get to my New:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", new { id = Model.ClientID})
```

from controller to view ( passing clientID not CountyID )

```
 public ActionResult Create(int id=0)
    {
        dbClient Client = db.Clients.Find(id);
        if (Client == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(Client);
    }
```

in the view: **Here is the issue , being that i want to create a county and not use an icollection of countys from clients but at the same time would like to show what client we are creating this county for**

```
@model OilNGasWeb.ModelData.dbClient 

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create County</h2>

@Html.Partial("_CreateCounty", Model.County) <----** Here ** Model.County is a string and Model.Countys is an icollection, i just want the normal model ???

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", new { id=Model.ClientID})
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

the partial view: **Seems to be freaking out because an Icollection or string is being passed -.- but i jsut want the model because im assuming thats what i need for the MVC Framework to create the insert properly?**

```
@model OilNGasWeb.ModelData.dbCounty

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Countys</legend>
  //data
  //data
  //data
</fieldset>
```

Im sorry if this doesnt make sence please advise what you need of me still learning mvc

**Allow me to revise the question above in something i know better**

Think of a vb.net application

(you have clients and there id's in a list)
after selecting a client you want to show another list ( this time editable ) with countys information
(now you only want to grab countys information, create an insert line for the database with the clients chosen clientID)

that explain it any better, having a hard time creating something like this for MVC

another option would be somehow on create new county, to include a dropdown list of clients ( and their respective IDs) and using the id along with the editable county info?

Comment: Why are you passing the ClientID instead of the CountyID?

Comment: good question, i think, anyway the reason i pass it instead of CountyID is because in my Database all Countys are based on CountyID but aswell as ClientID, therefor when i create a new County it must have the ClientID passed to it, and not a CountyID since it is autoincremented on insert time.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought.  Just making sure.  I'll post an answer shortly.

Comment: Ok thanks, also if it helps any ... i have also tried passing countys info that matched a clientID but it happens to pull in data for the last county of the client ( maybe just emptying those would be a fix ) but a bad fix i guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're tracking which counties belong to each client, I don't see why you would need to pass anything besides the ClientID for creation.

So your create view might look something like

```
@model OilNGasWeb.ModelData.dbClient 

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create County</h2>

@Html.Partial("_CreateCounty", new OilNGasWeb.ModelData.dbCounty() { clientID = Model.ClientID } ) <!-- pass the client ID to the partial

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", new { id=Model.ClientID})
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

For your Edit/Delete/View Details views, you should be able to just pass the CountyID or the object itself from the model.

Comment: and the respective _CreateCounty View would look like? cause from what i understand in order for the MVC Framework to know what model to use i have to declare the model uptop as in @ model OilNGasWeb.modelData.dbCounty for the Partial ( wich i thought wouldnt work when passing model.clientID) - or does it somehow still know how to create it ?  also would i still use lambda expressions to fill the @ HTML.EditorFor and Label for fields or do i leave them blank? in wich case can't i just put them all into the Original Create view instead of creating a partial?

Comment: in other words wouldnt i have to pass countys to my partial?

Comment: Ah yes, so essentially you'll just create a new dbCounty object, with the clientID already assigned, and then pass it through to your View.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: explain  """new OilNGasWeb.ModelData.dbCounty( ClientID = Model.ClientID)))""" i think maybe your using the wrong variables but damn thats awesome if it end up working, im having issues with specifically **ClientID = Model.ClientID** says doesnt exists and Model.ClientID = Model.ClientID is redundant...

Comment: It creates a new dbCounty object and assigns the value Model.ClientID to the ClientID property, try rewriting it to
new OilNGasWeb.ModelData.dbCounty() { ClientID = Model.ClientID })) and see if that works.

Comment: You should also take a look at [constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173115.aspx), that will slightly explain what's going on behind the scenes here.

Comment: Thanks will do, think i could email you on this kinda stuff for further issues?

Comment: Not a problem, I can't promise much though, it's been a while since I've worked on MVC and I'll have to refresh myself often. Are you using Entity Framework in your project as well?

Comment: Sure am. It was either learn something new ( Entity Framework ) or go oldschool, and though i know the  oldschool it may be benefitial to learn it.